# Using Talend Repository

Tags: version-control, versioning, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. 
I am looking for a way to use versioning for our project. 
Does Talend Repository able to do it? 
What is the benefit of using repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can do versionning for your project in talend. 
And Moreover you can do a versionning for each job.

- File -> project parameter -> general -> version (for all project version)
- In the property of job (for unique job version upgrade)

Moreover you can use a SVN in the paid version of talend (not the Talend open Studio).
This SVN allow you to work together on a same project.
When a people work on a job the job is locked and the other people can only see it, not modify it.
You need to unlock the job or to ask people to close it to modify.

You can upgrade the version of job when you want in the property of the job.

EDIT :

If you want to work with a team with the free version you can't use default SVN.

You need to import/export job. It's little bit bad but with a little adaptation. You can use the versioning of job.

I have listen that some company develop their own SVN.

Comment: I want to work together with a team on the same project in the free version. Will the versioning you mentioned work ?

Comment: But maybe someone will have a better solution. Actually that what I do in my job I use the free version

Comment: Since v6.0, the Talend Studion (paid version) supports GIT integration too.